# @SpringBootTest without declaring every needed class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

At the moment i need to tell the @SpringBootTest annotation which classes i need for so test. If i won't do that, the classes are not found in the test application context. Except of declaring in every test each single class i just want to provide some kind of configuration class, which defines all needed classes for the test.

At the moment the test is working with the following annotations:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = {"spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl"},
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = {
        CategoryController.class,
        CategoryService.class,
        CategoryValidationService.class,
        CategoryNameLengthValidator.class,
        CategoryPositionUniquenessValidator.class,
        GlobalExceptionHandler.class
    }
)
```

I tried to create an Configuration class and removed the classes from the @SpringBootTest annotation, but then the classes weren't found:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = {"spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl"},
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
)
```

And the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.it.mypackage"})
public class ContextConfiguration {
}
```

But it didn't worked if i don't tell the @SpringBootTest annotation which classes i need during test.

Error which appears:

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.bbraun.cit.dlm.controller.CategoryControllerIT]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5b7a8434, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@5c45d770, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@2ce6c6ec, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1bae316d, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@147a5d08, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@6676f6a0, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@7cbd9d24, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@1672fe87, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@5026735c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@1b45c0e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@11f0a5a1, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@10f7f7de]
[background-preinit] WARN org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder - For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that Spring Boot has not discovered the classes. 
Check if your path of the TestClasses coresponds with your Classes that you want test.

If your class is here:

```
/src/main/java/com/example/app/MainApplication.java
```

then the path to the test class must look like this:

```
/src/test/java/com/example/app/MainApplicationTest.java
```

If the path is not like this you have import the classes to SpringBootTest with classes=....